# Implement Cloudant change feed on local OpenWhisk

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, openwhisk

I have a local install of OpenWhisk (vagrant based), and a local install of Cloudant (the free one from the `ibmcom/cloudant-developer` container).

Both work separately as expected.

Now, using Bluemix, I can use the `/whisk.system/cloudant` package to use its feeds in my triggers, to for example watch for changes on a specific database.

Locally, this package is missing. I tried to copy the actions and feeds I needed using `wsk action get /whisk.system/cloudant/changes` (for example) but it seems there's another missing piece of the puzzle as the feed action refers to a cloudanttriggers location I never saw before:

```
function cloudantHelper(endpoint, verb, name, input) {
    var url = 'http://' + endpoint + '/cloudanttriggers/' + name;
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request({
            method : verb,
            url : url,
            json: input
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            ...
        });
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Any idea how to implement Cloudant Change feed on a local openwhisk installation?

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** You're looking for the CloudantProvider. See https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk-package-cloudant

To use the Cloudant feed OpenWhisk needs an additional component to actually listen to changes in Cloudant (the CouchDB `_changes` feed essentially) and fire the triggers in OpenWhisk. The feed-action you see talks to that service to setup a handler, which listens to `_changes` in the database you provide. It then fires the trigger specified once it receives a change.

Comment: Hi Markus - and thanks. Have you tried this install yourself? The instructions are very scarse and I am pretty confused about what to do to deploy this provider.

Comment: I agree the instructions are very scarse. You'll have to first build the image using `gradle` and then deploy it. Unfortunately, there is no ansible playbook in there to achieve that.

Comment: Oh, I´m starting to understand. The provider is just a nodejs app constantly polling the db and then calling the ow trigger...